# Convert a fillable PDF to CSV file

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pdf-conversion

I have a fillable PDF that contains multiple tables and I want to convert it to a CSV file using Python.

When I try to open the PDF with anything other than Adobe Acrobat Reader I get this message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOaA4.png)

What I have tried so far:

```
import PyPDF2
import fitz
import csv
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Prompt user to select input PDF file
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
pdf_file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")])

# Open the PDF file
pdf_file = fitz.open(pdf_file_path)

# Extract text from PDF file
pdf_text = ''
for page_num in range(pdf_file.page_count):
    page = pdf_file[page_num]
    pdf_text += str(page.get_text("text"))

# Split text into lines and columns
lines = pdf_text.split('\n')
columns = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]

# Save data to CSV file
csv_file_path = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '.csv')
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in columns:
        writer.writerow(row)

print(f"CSV file saved at {csv_file_path}")
```

What I have observed so far is that the pdf_file.page_count variable is always 1 and if I
`print(pdf_text)` it will give me the exact same message as when trying to open the pdf without Adobe Acrobat Reader.

When the CSV file is saved it will output this [CSV file error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYJE2.png)

I wonder if is stricly because of how the PDF file was created.